# Avoid hard coding resource name in edit path helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hope you guys don't mind if I ask this question using a syllogism...

`<%= link_to "Show", thing_path(@thing.id) %>`

is to

`<%= link_to "Show", @thing %>`

as

`<%= link_to "Show", edit_thing_path(@thing.id) %>`

is to ???

I want to use that edit path helper without hard coding the resource name so I can abstract this bit of code into a partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_polymorphic_path(@thing) %>
```

--

You'll be best using a [polymorphic path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html), as described here.

The difference you have is when you send a single object to the `link_to` helper, it's able to digest a path based on the `model_name` of the object. This is okay for `show` methods... but what about `edit`?

`Edit` has its own path - you have to explicitly define it in a `helper`; and as a result, I would suggest you can't just call an `object` to generate the path. Instead, the [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) helper will help you load the correct edit path based on the object you send